# Return all posts for a custom taxonomy id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have this code that should return all the posts that related to the taxonomy id, but it returns the last 5 posts.

```
<?php 
$leaderships = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'      => 'leadership',
'posts_per_page' => 11,
'tax_query'      => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'leadership-committee', 
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => 13,
    ),
),
));
?>
```

posts_per_page is not working here, Any help to get all the posts.

Thanks

Comment: What is your posts per page settings in the settings (I guess 5?). Have you tried setting it to -1 to retrieve all posts?

Comment: posts is set to 10 in admin settings (is this what you mean) , I tried  -1 but still show 5. It show 5 even in the single taxonomy page

Comment: Do you have a URL that I can look at?

Comment: The code above is in page template, but this is the URL for single tax http://localhost/hemmatshabab/?leadership-committee=management-committee

Comment: I can't access that it's a local resource.

Comment: So what do you think the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried removing the 2 excess comma's in the array definition?

Comment: Yes removed but still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one for help, I discovered that that the problem is from my theme admin area that was limiting the posts to 5 and fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer of the above question...

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 619,
        ),
    ),
 );

 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 if($loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>'."<br/>";
    endwhile;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the simplest way possible:

```
<?php 
$leaderships = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'      => 'leadership',
'posts_per_page' => -1
));
?>
```

If it returns all posts from "leadership" custom post type, then narrow it with 'tax_query' and check if You have more than 5 entries of custom post type "leadership" that are in custom taxonomy named "leadership-committee" in its created child (category/tag like) with id of 13.

Beside that, all looks ok in query.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that the problem is from my theme admin area that was limiting the posts to 5 and fixed now.

Comment: Either case, -1 shouls show all posts, not limited by wp settings.